# Most painless way to restore Windows 7 bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bootloader

What is the most painless way to restore the Windows 7 bootloader without a Windows DVD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/blog/2010/welcome-to-easybcd-2/) can do this, but to do it manually you can do the following:

1. Copy `bootmgr` to the root of your volume (probably `C:\`).
2. Run `bootsect /nt60 /mbr /sys` (I hope I got the command-line right)

I'm not sure where I found `bootsect` -- it might have been in `C:\Boot`, or it might have been in the [Windows AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5753) or on the Windows CD. You'll have to search for it.

Comment: The command line is correct.

Comment: For best results, it should be your [system volume](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html).