# Will deleting partitions affect my hard drive in any way?

Tags: windows-7, linux, opensuse, boot-partition

I installed a Suse partition of around 200 Gigabytes on my hard drive, primarily running Windows 7. I am sick of Suse's crap, and just want to get rid of the OS and get that partition back for Windows' use. Is it as simple as that partition gets deleted,and I can choose what partition that space goes to, or is it communal that all partitions can access? I know next to nothing about partitions, so any help would be great. Also, if someone knows HOW to delete partitions, that would be a great help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, deleting Partition does not affect other partitions. (unless you manage to mess things up completely).

For Windows7 go to: Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management (as Administrator) -> Storage -> Disk Management

There you can delete the partition and resize the other.

Just a warning: do not delete the 100MB system partition, thats the boot partition for windows.

Comment: Ok, I just deleted my Suse partition. I am missing the part where I can move the free space into my primary Windows data partition. It just says "Free space". What should I do?

Comment: Try to extend `C:`, this might not be possible because it's the active partition. In this case you can either just create another partition and use that space or you have to boot from a (linux) live CD and use a tool like gParted.

Comment: Final question- Would Ubuntu be the best option, or do all Linux Live CD's have gParted?

Comment: ubuntu is possible, or just gparted live http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: Windows won't boot after I deleted the partition and restarted, it goes to some kind of GRUB command prompt thing, and theres no noticeable way to boot to windows. I will get you a picture of the screen when I get back to that computer later today, but any ideas? Would gParted fix this? Sorry I'm having so much trouble.

Comment: looks like the bootloader got messed up, there are dozens of tutorials online to restore the win7 loader, check out this question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/338520/most-painless-way-to-restore-windows-7-bootloader